# WordPressからKusanagiを削除するには？

Tags: wordpress

WordPressからKusanagiを削除するにはどうすればいいでしょうか？

---

サーバーの移転作業中です。

旧サーバーで
phpMyAdminでデータベースをバックアップ。
wordpressのドキュメントルート以下のファイルをすべてバックアップ。

新サーバーで
データベースをリストア。
ファイルをリストア。

いまのところ新サーバーでサイトが正常に動いています。

ただし、1点だけ問題が。
WordPressの管理画面で、
`外観`、`プラグイン`、`ユーザー`、`ツール`、`設定`などのメニューに混ざって
`KUSANAGI`というのが表示されています。

旧サーバーはさくらのVPSなのですが、
OSとしてKusanagi for WordPressみたいなものを選んでいました。

Kuasnagiは、CentOSとWordPressの間にあるミドルウェア的なものだと理解しているのですが、
新サーバーにはそもそもKusanagiがありません。

---

移行したWordPressのファイル群の中に
`wp-content/mu-plugins/kusanagi-core`のようなディレクトリがあります。

これを削除してしまえばいいのか？
なにかアンインストール用のツールやコマンドのようなものが用意されているのか？

また、データベースにはKusanagi用のテーブルが作成されていないのか？

Kusanagiの利用をやめる場合の正規の手順が分かりません。

Kusanagi公式のドキュメントを探しましたがアンインストールや削除に関する記述は見つけられませんでした。
https://kusanagi.tokyo/document/

---

Kusanagiの観点から、
WordPressからKusanagiを消す方法についてご存知の方がいればアドバイスをください。

また、WordPress側の視点から、
「`wp-content/mu-plugins`にあるものはこういう手順で削除するのが一般的」
みたいな知見をお持ちの方がいればアドバイスをください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下の記事が参考になるかもしれません。

[既存のWordPressサイトをドメインを変えずにmixhostに移行する手順](https://affi-sapo.com/1133/)

> #### KUSANAGI環境からmixhostに移行した場合
>
> KUSANAGI環境のサーバーからmixhostに移行した場合、次のようなKUSANAGIの環境設定画面が残ることがあります。
> この場合、ファイルマネージャでKUSANAGIのプラグインを削除します。
>
> **場所1**
>
> ```
> public_html > ドメインフォルダ > wp-content > mu-plugins
>
> 削除ファイル：
> kusanagi-wp-configure.php
> wp-kusanagi.php
> ```
>
> **場所2**
>
> ```
> public_html > ドメインフォルダ > wp-content > mu-plugins > kusanagi-core
>
> 削除ファイル：
> 全て（フォルダ含む）
> ```
>
> **場所3**
>
> ```
> public_html > ドメインフォルダ > wp-content
>
> 削除ファイル：
> advanced-cache.php
> ```
>
> 削除をしたら再ログインをして、KUSANAGIの管理画面が表示されなければOKです。
>
> 本当に削除していいのか不安な場合は、名前の変更でも大丈夫です。
> しばらく使用して、問題ないと感じたら削除してください。

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。
わたしのシチュエーションと近い方の記録ですね。
''mu-plugins''の中身と''advanced-cache.php''をバックアップしたうえで削除してみました。
管理画面から`KUSANAGI`というメニューは無事に消えました。
目標の9割方は達成です。
「DBにゴミが残っていないのか」は気になるので、もう少しだけ質問はオープンのままにさせて頂きます。

Comment: DB に関しても事前にバックアップを取ったうえで、明らかにそれと分かるテーブル等を手動で削除、自信が無ければそのままにしておく…といった対応になると思います。残してあると問題があるケースを除いて、下手に弄っておかしくするよりはそのままでもいいのかなと個人的には思います。